# why is my javascript 'scrollIntoView' not working?

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I am using javascript trying to highlight and scroll to text on my html page.

(It's the same functionality as 'Ctrl-F' (find) in a browser. A school project.)

The highlight is working, which indicates my variable 'targetElement' is set correctly.

The scrolling is not working.
The 'scrollIntoView' appears to be doing nothing.

I have tried:

- changing the order of the highlighting and scrolling statements.
- changing and completely removing 'scrollIntoView' options.
- delaying the 'scrollIntoView' (as in the code below).
- searching similar questions on stackoverflow

All with no effect.

```
        function scrollToOccurrence(currentOccurrenceIndex) {

            // reset previous span
            if (currentOccurrenceIndex > 0) {
                let targetElement = document.getElementById('span' + (currentOccurrenceIndex - 1));
                targetElement.className = 'yellow'
            }
            
            // set current span
            let targetElement = document.getElementById('span' + currentOccurrenceIndex);
            targetElement.className = 'orange'

            // scroll to the current occurrence
            setTimeout(function () {
                targetElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'} );
            }, 500);

        }
```

For my testing, the only css I have is:

```
<style>
    .yellow {
        background: yellow;
    }
    .orange {
        background: orange;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Aside: Remember to declare local variables with `let`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Why do you set `targetElement` twice?

Comment: I have added 'let' to the local variable.
(I retested my code, but no difference, as one would expect.)

Notice that ```targetElement``` is set with a different index each time.

The first time to reset the colour of the previously found item.
The second to set the colour of the current item.

Comment: `let` is block-scoped, so declaring the variable inside the `if` doesn't affect the variable in the rest of the function. Also, the second assignment overrides the first one, since it's not conditional -- it should probably be in `else`.

Comment: Oh, never mind. I see the first one is just for resetting the previous element.

Comment: As I asked above, please post a [mre] so we can try this ourselves.

Comment: My program is now working.

To create minimalist code, I started by copying the original troublesome code into a new file.

I deleted comments and blank lines. I can't see that I have changed anything else.
The issue has gone away.
I don't know if I have removed any unprintable/control characters.

@Barmar  Thank you for your responses.  Much appreciated.